# Speeding up a nested for loop

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I've been working on speeding up the following function, but with no results:

```
function beta = beta_c(k,c,gamma)
beta = zeros(size(k));
E = @(x) (1.453*x.^4)./((1 + x.^2).^(17/6));
for ii = 1:size(k,1)
    for jj = 1:size(k,2)
        E_int = integral(E,k(ii,jj),10000);
        beta(ii,jj) = c*gamma/(k(ii,jj)*sqrt(E_int));
    end
end
end
```

Up to now, I solved it this way:

```
function beta = beta_calc(k,c,gamma)
k_1d = reshape(k,[1,numel(k)]);
E_1d =@(k) 1.453.*k.^4./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int = zeros(1,numel(k_1d));
parfor ii = 1:numel(k_1d)
E_int(ii) = quad(E_1d,k_1d(ii),10000);
end
beta_1d = c*gamma./(k_1d.*sqrt(E_int));
beta = reshape(beta_1d,[size(k,1),size(k,2)]);
end
```

Seems to me, it didn't really enhance performances. What do you think about this?

Would you mind to shed a light?

I thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I am gonna introduce some theoretical background involving my question.
Generally, beta is to be calculated as follows

[image]

Therefore, in the reduced case of unidimensional k array, E_int may be calculated as

```
E = 1.453.*k.^4./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int = 1.5 - cumtrapz(k,E);
```

or, alternatively as

```
E_int(1) = 1.5;
for jj = 2:numel(k)
E =@(k) 1.453.*k.^4./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int(jj) = E_int(jj - 1) - integral(E,k(jj-1),k(jj));
end
```

Nonetheless, `k` is currently a matrix `k(size1,size2)`.

Comment: Your best bet would be to compile the function as a mex - it will be tons faster.

Comment: @fpe Off-topic: in current versions of MATLAB I have never witnessed `arrayfun` to be faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: I am not familiar with integral, but can't it take two matrices in ?

Comment: @EitanT: I'd btw like to optimize the performance of the above function. May vectorization be the answer?

Comment: @Pavan: I guess integral needs scalars as integration limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach, parallelize, because it's easy using `spmd` or `parfor`. Instead of `integral` consider `quad`, see this [link](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/quad_parfor/quad_parfor.html) for examples...

Comment: I just edited my question, inputing parfor in the expression of `beta_calc`. The execution time for a case study `magic(100)` is half as before. Quite a good result, but I do not know if good enough

Comment: your hint seems, by now, the most reasonable solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I like this question.

*The problem:* the function `integral` takes as integration limits only scalars. Hence, it is difficult to vectorize the computation of of `E_int`.

*A clue:* there seems to be  lot of redundancy in integrating the *same* function over and over from `k(ii,jj)` to infinity...

*Proposed solution:* How about sorting the values of `k` from smallest to largest and integrating `E_sort_int(si) = integral( E, sortedK(si), sortedK(si+1) );` with `sortedK( numel(k) + 1 ) = 10000;`. Then the full value of `E_int = cumsum( E_sort_int );` (you only need to "undo" the sorting and reshape it back to the size of `k`).

Comment: actually E_int as integral limits should assume |k| and Inf; btw, as you argue, I can calculate E_int in an alternative way that I'll post as edit to the main question (notice that I'll present it in the case k is a 1-d array)

Comment: I started thinking that perhaps it's easier mexing a C function accounting for the one I call now in Matlab; at least concerning `integral`